# NativeScript: Azure Pipeline for iOS fails because there are no accounts registered with xcode even though certificates seem to be installed

Tags: ios, xcode, azure, macos, nativescript

I was following this blog post https://blog.nativescript.org/ios-on-windows/ to build a NativeScript app for iOS even though I don't have access to a macOS machine.

Following that blog post, I created my certificates using OpenSSL 1.1.1 on my Windows 10 PC, registered my iPhone with my Apple Developer account and then created a pipeline in Azure with the following configuration (I had to make some minor changes to what is shown in the blog post):

```
trigger:
  - main

name: '1.1.$(DayOfYear)$(rev:rr)'
variables:
  - group: MyiOSVars

jobs:
  - job: BuildApple
    pool:
      vmImage: macOS-latest
    steps:
      - checkout: self
        clean: true
        path: "MyApp"

      - task: NodeTool@0
        inputs:
          versionSpec: '14.x'

      - script: |
          pip install six
          pip3 install six
        displayName: 'Install six'

      - script: |
          npm i -g nativescript
        displayName: 'Install nativescript'

      - script: |
          npm --version
          node --version

          ruby --version
          gem query --local
          echo **************************************
          pip --version
          pip3 --version
          pip show six
          pip3 show six
        displayName: 'Show NPM version'

      - task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
        displayName: 'Install an Apple certificate'
        inputs:
          certSecureFile: '$(apple_cert_secure_file_id)'
          certPwd: '$(p12password)'

      - task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
        displayName: 'Install an Apple provisioning profile'
        inputs:
          provProfileSecureFile: '$(apple_provisioning_profile_file_id)'

      - script: |
          ns --version --json
        displayName: 'Show nativescript version'

      - script: |
          ns doctor
#          ns build ios --team-id
#          ns build ios --provision
        displayName: 'Run ns doctor'

      - script: |
          ns build ios --for-device
        displayName: 'Run NativeScript iOS build'

      - task: CopyFiles@2
        displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
        inputs:
          SourceFolder: '$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)'
          Contents: |
            **/*.ipa
          TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
          flattenFolders: true
          preserveTimestamp: true

      - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
        displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
        inputs:
          PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
```

As you can see, I used `ns build ios --team-id` and `ns build ios --provision` to check if my certificates are being recognized by the NativeScript CLI. The output of those commands is (I replaced the actual values with placeholders )

```
┌────────────────────┬────────────┐
│ Team Name          │ Team ID    │
│ 'MY TEAM NAME'     │ 123456789  │
└────────────────────┴────────────┘
Please provide team id or team name with the --teamId options.
Searching for devices...
┌──────────────────────────────────────────┬──────────────────┬─────────────┬─────────┐
│ Provision Name / Provision UUID / App Id │ Team             │ Type / Due  │ Devices │
│                                          │                  │             │         │
│ 'MyApp on John's iPhone'                 │ MY TEAM NAME     │ Development │ 1 total │
│ 12345-12345-12345-12345                  │ (123456789)      │ 6 Sep 2024  │         │
│ 123456789.com.myapp                      │                  │             │         │
└──────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────┴─────────────┴─────────┘

There are also 0 non-eligable provisioning profiles.

Please provide provisioning profile uuid or name with the --provision option.
```

So to me it looks like my certificates have been installed successfully.

However, the command `ns build ios --for-device` fails with the following messages

```
Building project...
Xcode requires a team id to be specified when building for device.
You can specify the team id by setting the DEVELOPMENT_TEAM setting in build.xcconfig file located in App_Resources folder of your app, or by using the --teamId option when calling run, debug or livesync commands.
Found and using the following development team installed on your system: MY TEAM NAME (123456789)
Searching for devices...
Xcode build...
note: Building targets in dependency order
/Users/runner/work/1/MyApp/platforms/ios/MyApp.xcodeproj: error: There are no accounts registered with Xcode. Add your developer account to Xcode (in target 'MyApp' from project 'MyApp')
/Users/runner/work/1/MyApp/platforms/ios/MyApp.xcodeproj: error: No profiles for 'com.myapp' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.myapp'. (in target 'MyApp' from project 'MyApp')
note: Run script build phase 'NativeScript PreBuild' will be run during every build because the option to run the script phase "Based on dependency analysis" is unchecked. (in target 'MyApp' from project 'MyApp')
note: Run script build phase 'NativeScript PreLink' will be run during every build because the option to run the script phase "Based on dependency analysis" is unchecked. (in target 'MyApp' from project 'MyApp')
note: Run script build phase 'NativeScript PostBuild' will be run during every build because the option to run the script phase "Based on dependency analysis" is unchecked. (in target 'MyApp' from project 'MyApp')
/Users/runner/work/1/MyApp/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'SAMKeychain' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/1/MyApp/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'MNFloatingActionButton' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/1/MyApp/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'MNFloatingActionButton-MNFloatingActionButton' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/1/MyApp/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'QBImagePickerController' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/1/MyApp/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/1/MyApp/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'QBImagePickerController-QBImagePicker' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/1/MyApp/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'TOCropViewController-TOCropViewControllerBundle' from project 'Pods')
** ARCHIVE FAILED **

Command xcodebuild failed with exit code 65
##[error]Bash exited with code '127'.
```

So, at first that command complains about no team being given but then it seems to correctly use the team of my installed developer certificate. However, a few steps later, xcode fails because no developer account and no provisioning profiles are given, even though the NativeScript CLI shows them to be installed.

What am I missing?